# how do I tell when a c++ program is waiting for input?

Tags: c++, python, cout, cin

I'm trying to control a simple c++ program through python.  The program works by prompting the user for input.  The prompts are not necessarily endl terminated.  What I would like to know is if there is a way to tell from python that the c++ program is no longer generating output and has switched to requesting input.
Here's an simple example:

c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Enter a number ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << x << " squared = " << x * x << endl;
}
```

python:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import subprocess, sys
dproc = subprocess.Popen('./y', stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while (True) :
    dout = dproc.stdout.read(1)
    sys.stdout.write(dout)
    dproc.stdin.write("22\n")
```

This sort of works but writes to dproc.stdin too much.  What I am looking for instead is a way to read everything from dproc.stdout *until* the program is ready for input and then write to dproc.stdout .

If possible, I would like to do this w/o modifying the c++ code.  ( However, I have tried playing with buffering on the c++ side but it didn't seem to help )

Thank you for any responses.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of a sufficiently general paradigm for detecting that the remote end is waiting for input. I can think of basic ways, but also of situations in which they will fail. Examples:

1. Read with a non-blocking pipe/socket until no input arrives: the response might be interrupted by the process writing to disk, waiting for a reply from a database etc.
2. Wait until the process becomes idle: a background thread might still be running.

You'll have to be aware of the protocol used by the application you're trying to control. In a sense, you'll be designing an *interpreter* for that process. [`pexpect`](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) is a toolset for Python based on this idea.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html).

Comment: I looked at pexpect.  The pexpect functionality appears to work by reading the output that the c++ program generates and parsing that data.  I might end up doing this but I was looking for something more general that would work even if you don't have any idea what output the c++ program will generate.

Comment: There's no way to know whether a program is waiting for input; pipes just don't provide that functionality, unfortunately.

Comment: @Dave: if the process is using `select()` to determine availability of an answer (i.e "active wait"), it wouldn't block while waiting for input anyways. This is probably why pipes don't provide that functionality in the first place.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid that was going to be the case.  Still, at some level, it's a little surprising.  A user can do this - just look for the blinking cursor prompt.  It seems like it would be natural that if program A is running program B then  A would be able to tell if B is waiting for input - just as a person could.

Comment: Pipes are explicitly designed so that there's a buffer between A and B, such that when A has data to send, it isn't held up waiting for B to be ready for it, and when B is ready for data, it isn't held up waiting for A to send it. So you may find you can just send the data and the receiving program will accept it when it's ready to take it (unless it explicitly flushes its input buffer to eliminate stray input; some programs do).

Comment: Thank you,kindall. Yes, I can just send the data and the receiving program will accept it when it's ready to take it.  That does fine for getting data to the receiving program.  In fact, this is what happens in the example that I originally posted.   However, I also am interested in knowing all the output that has been sent to cout before each request for input is made.  Queuing up responses does not help me with that.

Comment: By now it's pretty clear that the answer to my question is either "it can't be done" or "it's hard to do".  Either way, I'll find some other way to deal with the larger task.  Thanks to everyone who responded.  I may end up doing something with pexepct which was new to me.  That said, it still seems to me that bash must do something of this nature when it decides whether or not to display a blinking cursor when a child process is waiting for input.  Any insights into either what is going on in that case or why it is different would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a trick going on there. The blinking cursor is actually displayed all the time. It just blinks *off* first, and every time a character is printed, it resets to the beginning of its blink cycle. So it only really shows up when nothing has been printed for a while. Try running a long-running command or script; the cursor will be blinking even though you're not at a prompt.

Comment: Thanks kindall - both for the quickness of the response and the clarity of the response.

Comment: Also, I should add that it's not bash displaying the cursor, it's the terminal program, and that's the reason the cursor trickery is necessary in the first place. The terminal doesn't know when bash is waiting for input any more than your Python script knows when your C++ subprocess is waiting for input. Same exact issue. :-)